Question on a variation of the Fourier expansion
Question 9.26 from Whittaker and Watson's $\textit{ A Course of Modern Analysis}$ asks: Assuming the possibility of expanding $f(x)$ in a uniformly convergent series of the form $ \sum_{k} A_k \sin(kx)$, where $k$ is a root of the equation $k\cos(ak)+b\sin(ak)=0$ and the summation is extended to all positive roots of the equation, determine the constants $A_k$.
Could I get a hint for how to approach this? Making the simplifying assumption $a=b=1$ reduces the problem to finding the coefficients $A_k$ of an expansion of the form
$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \sin(\lambda_kx)$, where the sequence $\{\lambda_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an enumeration of all the positive solutions of $\tan x = x $. Is such an expansion actually valid for some class of functions $f$, and can I get a hint for how to compute the coefficients? Any help is appreciated.
